# Return string via stored procedure using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, enterprise-library

I have a table which has a column that is being auto-generated based on other columns in the table. I am attempting to insert data into the table using a stored procedure and then return the auto-generate column. In the stored procedure below, `@Num` represents the auto-generated column.

The approach I am taking here works with regard to inserting the data into the database. What isn't working is returning `@Num` from the `Insert` stored procedure. Is what I am trying to do possible. If so what am I doing wrong? If not, is there an alternative method to accomplish this?

This is my C#. When I run this, `returnValue` comes back null.

```
   internal static bool InsertApplication(Something something)
   {
       object returnValue;
       string sql = "usp_InsertSproc";
       returnValue = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString").ExecuteScalar(sql, new Object[] { something.First_Name, something.Last_Name });
   //I'd like to be able to access the @Num value from the Sproc here
   }
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertSproc]
(
@First_Name varchar(50),
@Last_Name varchar(50),
@Num Varchar(500) Output
)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;

  INSERT INTO [Table] ([First_Name], [Last_Name]) 
  VALUES (@First_Name, @Last_Name, )

  Return @Num
```

This is what my table looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table]
(
   [First_Name] VARCHAR(50),
   [Last_Name] VARCHAR(50),
   [Num] AS ([dbo].[SetCMP]([Num]))
)
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `@Num`?

Comment: To wit, you should `SELECT @Num` rather than return it.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: If it is an output parameter, do you still need to "return" it? Isn't setting it enough?

Comment: @ShaiCohen I think he means it would be a better approach to select `@Num` rather than have it as an output parameter.

Comment: @shree.pat18 added what Num is generated from to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table]
(
    [First_Name] VARCHAR(50),
    [Last_Name] VARCHAR(50),
    [Num] AS [First_Name] + [Last_Name] + '!'
)
```

Your C# should be fine.  Change your stored procedure to something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertSproc]
    @First_Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Last_Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO [Table] ([First_Name], [Last_Name])
    OUTPUT inserted.[Num]
    VALUES (@First_Name, @Last_Name)
GO

EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertSproc]
    @First_Name = 'Tom',
    @Last_Name = 'Hunter'
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Num will be in your `returnValue` variable.

Comment: This works great, except @Num is generated by a function in it's definition, which generates the following error message. Column 'inserted.Cmpl_Num' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. I've updated my post with what the table looks like.

Comment: Nevermind, I've altered my SQL so that your solution works. I am going to mark your response as the answer.